# bundle a project include my own modules using pyinstaller on linux

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller, distutils

I have a project in this structure on my linux machine:

```
project/
       changelog
       README
       src/
          install.sh
          myproject.py
          modules/
                 f.py 
                 d.py
                 s.py
                 __init__.py
```

Now I want to run pyinstaller:

```
$ pyinstaller myproject.py -p modules/
```

I run like so:

```
$ ./dist/myproject/myproject
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
myproject returned -1
```

Comment: Looks like it might not be finding the `f` package module. Try diagnosing the problem by inserting a `-d` or `--debug` option when you run `pyinstaller` between its name and the `myproject.py` which will "Tell the bootloader to issue progress messages while initializing and starting the bundled app."

Comment: Try replacing `myproject.py` with a script that doesn't use the package and see if that works properly.